# codeigniter doesn't display the page requested

Tags: php, mysql, apache, codeigniter

I have a working MVC framework using codeigniter. The codebase is located in /var/www/project,
where project follows the same structure as codeigniter. I have placed a info.php file under /var/www/project, which is the basic phpinfo() script. On typing

```
http://localhost/project/info.php
```

the page displays the information as it should.

My config.php under /var/www/project/application/config has been configured so that the [base_url] is : `http://localhost/project`

The 'project' is trying to connect to database : 'development' and the database.php has been configured properly ( afaik). On enabling the debug mode in database.php, it doesnt throw any error which makes me think that there is no issue as far as accessing the database is conerned( Though I can be wrong).

Also doing a ' ps aux | grep apache' shows:

`root     14892  0.0  0.1 215404  9668 ?        Ss   17:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14896  0.0  0.2 223404 17324 ?        S    17:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14897  0.0  0.1 215896  7636 ?        S    17:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14898  0.0  0.1 218964 11460 ?        S    17:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14899  0.0  0.1 218956 11300 ?        S    17:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14901  0.0  0.1 216020  7680 ?        S    17:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14902  0.0  0.2 220268 13632 ?        S    17:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14903  0.0  0.1 216412  8988 ?        S    17:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14904  0.0  0.2 219756 13268 ?        S    17:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14905  0.0  0.2 223396 16840 ?        S    17:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15161  0.0  0.1 216008  7588 ?        S    17:49   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     16184  0.0  0.0   7640   928 pts/1    S+   18:55   0:00 grep --color=auto apache`

Usually if apache is not given the root privilege, this sort of issue might occur, but here the privilege is root. I am not sure where am I messing up the configuration part.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: It just doesnt display anything on the browser. Remains blank on Firefox. On Chrome it says: Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving `http://localhost/project/`. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Comment: you didn't mentioned about controller and loading view form the controller. ? have you ?

Comment: @SUMAN: Well the page isn't being loaded at all. Even if there was an error in Controller/View, it would have thrown an error on browser. The problem here is that the framework is not picking up the `base_url` for some reason.

Comment: in ci, the view doesn't load directly, first you have to make a controller and load view from that controller. Then, you will go like baseurl/controllername

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

And let us know if it changes anything in the output.

Also, if you're using cookies, set the $config['cookie_path'] = "/project";

Comment: I see the same behavior as when `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project'`. Intersting. So changing base_url has no impact. Why is it so? No cookies being used.

Comment: The codeigniter suppresses a lot of errors via @. Sometimes is difficult to trace what's going wrong. I suggest you to try changing the $config['uri_protocol'] variable from AUTO to other value that matches your current configuration and see if it gives you leads to the problem or if it solves it. Also take a look at apache error log and see if it's catching any errors.

Comment: Good catch: I see some error messages there

    `Sat May 03 19:32:03 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP      Warning:  require_once(/var/www/project/system/core/CodeIgniter.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/project/index.php on line 202
    [Sat May 03 19:32:03 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/project/system/core/CodeIgniter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/project/index.php on line 202
`

Looks like something to do with the permission. Any idea from this log?

Comment: Try changing directory owner and group first with the shell command "chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/project" and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Note that if that solved the issue, do not leave the files owned by www-data. Change the owner to root, the group to www-data and grant that no one can write the files except root (unless you've a really good reason to do so).

Comment: Which Directory are you speaking about? Is it /var/www/project. It is owned by root.

Comment: Grant that the user or group www-data can read the whole directory, subdirectories and files. Note that the child apache processes that read your www directory run as www-data.

Comment: chgrp -R www-data /var/www/project

Comment: Just execute the above command as root. This probably will solve your permissions issue.